# MySQL find child records where created date is before and after date from parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I'm using MySQL version 8.0.

I have 2 tables: `approvals` and `activities`

The `approvals` table has a one to many relationship with the `activities` table, IE: one `approvals` record can have many records in the `activities` table.

There will be records in the `activities` table created both before and after the record is created in the `approvals` table. It is ok for `activities` records to be created before the `approvals` record is created because the `activities` table is actually tied to another table that isn't important for this question and the `approvals` information is updated on the pre-existing `activities` table records after the `approvals` record is created.

What I am looking to do is to write a query that will display the `approvals` record information and then also display the information for the records from the `activities` table for the records that were created right before and after the `approvals` record was created.

[I have already mocked out the tables and my query on db-fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ZwcWdMJJfSLdo5es7gKTK/0)

Here are the scripts to create and populate the `approvals` and `activities` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `approvals` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `created` DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));

CREATE TABLE `activities` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `approvalId` INTEGER, `created` DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));

INSERT INTO `approvals` (`created`)
VALUES
('2020-10-04 10:30:05'),
('2020-10-04 10:42:21'),
('2020-10-05 11:24:47'),
('2020-10-06 15:35:35');

INSERT INTO `activities` (`approvalId`, `created`)
VALUES
(1, '2020-09-30 04:24:14'),
(1, '2020-10-01 12:21:05'),
(1, '2020-10-06 12:21:05'),
(1, '2020-10-07 14:29:22'),

(2, '2020-09-28 05:33:10'),
(2, '2020-10-04 09:21:05'),
(2, '2020-10-04 15:27:35'),
(2, '2020-10-07 01:44:12'),

(3, '2020-09-22 04:24:14'),
(3, '2020-10-04 12:21:05'),
(3, '2020-10-06 12:21:05'),
(3, '2020-10-07 14:29:22'),

(4, '2020-09-21 04:24:14'),
(4, '2020-10-04 14:21:05'),
(4, '2020-10-10 12:21:05'),
(4, '2020-10-12 14:29:22');
```

Here is the query that I have written:

```
SELECT `der`.`id` AS `aprvId`, 
    `oact1`.`id` AS `preActivityId`,
    `oact1`.`created` AS `prevActivityCreated`,        
    `der`.`created` AS `appCreatedDate`,    
    `oact2`.`id` AS `postActivityId`,
    `oact2`.`created` AS `postActivityCreated`    
FROM (
    SELECT `app`.`id`, 
        MAX(`act1`.`created`) AS `mxDate`,
        `app`.`created`,
        '' AS `mnDate`
    FROM `approvals` AS `app`
    JOIN `activities` AS `act1` ON `act1`.`approvalId` = `app`.`id`
    WHERE `act1`.`created` <= `app`.`created`
    GROUP BY `app`.`created`, `app`.`id`, `app`.`id`

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `app`.`id`,
        '' AS `mxDate`,
        `app`.`created`,
        MIN(`act1`.`created`) AS `mnDate`    
    FROM `approvals` AS `app`
    JOIN `activities` AS `act1` ON `act1`.`approvalId` = `app`.`id`    
    WHERE `act1`.`created` >= `app`.`created`
    GROUP BY `app`.`created`, `app`.`id`, `app`.`id`
) AS `der`
JOIN `activities` AS `oact1` ON `oact1`.`approvalId` = `der`.`id`
JOIN `activities` AS `oact2` ON `oact2`.`approvalId` = `der`.`id`
GROUP BY `der`.`id`, `oact1`.`id`, `oact2`.`id`, `der`.`created`
HAVING `prevActivityCreated` = MAX(`der`.`mxDate`) AND `postActivityCreated` = MAX(`der`.`mnDate`)
```

Here is the output of my query (again, this query works and this is the output that I need):

```
| aprvId | appCreatedDate      | preActivityId | prevActivityCreated | postActivityId | postActivityCreated |
| ------ | ------------------- | ------------- | ------------------- | -------------- | ------------------- |
| 1      | 2020-10-04 10:30:05 | 2             | 2020-10-01 12:21:05 | 3              | 2020-10-06 12:21:05 |
| 2      | 2020-10-04 10:42:21 | 6             | 2020-10-04 09:21:05 | 7              | 2020-10-04 15:27:35 |
| 3      | 2020-10-05 11:24:47 | 10            | 2020-10-04 12:21:05 | 11             | 2020-10-06 12:21:05 |
| 4      | 2020-10-06 15:35:35 | 14            | 2020-10-04 14:21:05 | 15             | 2020-10-10 12:21:05 |
```

It provides me with the data that I am looking for, my question is this: is there a a better or cleaner or more efficient way of getting this information?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I would think of doing this as:

```
select aa.*, ac_prev.*, ac_next.*
from (select ap.id, ap.created,
             max(case when ac.created < ap.created then ac.created end) as prev_created,
             min(case when ac.created > ap.created then ac.created end) as next_created
      from approvals ap cross join
           activities ac 
      group by ap.id, ap.created
     ) aa left join
     activities ac_prev
     on ac_prev.created = aa.prev_created left join
     activities ac_next
     on ac_next.created = aa.next_created;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fbeb70c27d4dfbc0cbab7226e03cf79) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: that query is close, but it returns 6 rows when only 4 should be returned. The result set of your query is similar to my result set but it is slightly different. Thanks though.

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak . . . This puts the matching activities on the same row with the approvals, which seems quite in the spirit of the question.

Comment: true, but it still creates multiple records for some of the `approvalId`s, like for `approvalId` of 3. It may seem nit picky, but I need the result set to only return 1 record for each `approvalId`, exactly how the result set from my query is.